# How to modify the default position of desktop icons

Tags: unity, 12.04, nautilus, launcher

[image: Unity Launcher over desktop icons]

Is it possible to modify the default **desktop icons position** so that icons move a little bit to right. If yes, how? As far as I know, there is no tweak for that in Nautilus.
When I click "Organize Desktop by Name", the icons get aligned to the left of Desktop: that's fine, but they're too close to the launcher when it's in **AUTO HIDE mode**. So when Launcher is revealed, it comes over icons.

Reproduce: Download some files from your browser or copy files/folders from a folder to the desktop, then these latter will be placed just like the screenshot. Their position is fine when the launcher is hidden, but when revealed, it hides a part of the icons.

There is no problem when LAUNCHER AUTO-HIDE MODE is disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the icons with your hands.one left click on the icon and hold the mouse then drag the icon and drop it a little bit to right.then right click on empty space in desktop and mark **keep aligned** to correct the minimal displacing of the icons due to manual alignment.

Comment: This is not what I needed. I already operated this way. Anyway, I am editing your answer and approving it.

Comment: @Hanynowsky I saw your edit and have rejected it since an edit should not be used for this. Please use a comment, or explain why the edit should go through.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, what you described in your question is a feature which the actual design of Unity' launcher vs Nautilus, does not implement yet. I recommend filing a bug against Unity to Launchpad as an enhancement feature. Unfortunately, no workaround is known for now.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have the option for "auto aligning" activated (sorry I don't know how it's the name in English).  If you turn off this option you can set the icons where you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not a matter of auto aligning (Keep Aligned), but the purpose is that when i Click "Organize by Name" the icons don't get too close to the launcher but a little bit more to right of the launcher. (Ex: When you download a file, it automatically go to the default position).